# Symfony: Form issue using Return type hinting in Doctrine Entity methods

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, php-7, return-type

I was being exceptionally diligent today and decided to return-type hint all of my symfony entity methods. So:

```
<?php

Class User {
    private string $username;
    public method getUsername(): string {}
}
```

all good and well, until I made a form to create a new user:

```
$user = new User();
$this->createForm(SignupType::class, $user);
```

when the form is displayed, Symfony automatically gets the properties of this new instance of `User $user`. But since it is a new instantiation, its `username` property is of course still `null`, which is an incorrect return type as it needs to be `string`.

Should I either:

1. have no return-type hinting in Symfony entities (meh);
2. set `$username = ''` (but hat kind of defeats the purpose of not allowing blanks and I can see all sorts of errors evolving); or
3. unmap the field on the symfony form
4. other possible solutions...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If an Entity Property cannot be `null` (*and you use PHP 7.1+*), then applying the [nullable return type declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php) sounds more like a dirty and fast workaround to maintain a direct data binding between Entities and Forms (*using the Symfony Form Component*).

A better global approach (*in my opinion*) is to decouple the Form data binding from your Doctrine Entities using a DTO (*Data Transfer Object*), that is a simple POPO (*Plain Old PHP Object*) to contain your form data.

Using a DTO will allow you to maintain a strict type hinting in your Doctrine Entities (*no loss of data consistency*) and will decouple Form data binding (*but also data validation*) from your Entities.

DTO's allows reusability and have many other advantages.

Some useful references about the use of DTO's with Symfony Forms:

- [Avoiding Entities in Forms (*by Iltar van der Berg*)](https://stovepipe.systems/post/avoiding-entities-in-forms)
- [Rethinking Form Development (*by Iltar van der Berg*)](https://stovepipe.systems/post/rethinking-form-development)
- [Symfony Forms 101 (*by Bernhard Schussek the creator of the Form component*)](https://speakerdeck.com/webmozart/symfony-forms-101)
- [Don't Use Entities in Symfony Forms. Use Custom Data Objects Instead](https://blog.martinhujer.cz/symfony-forms-with-request-objects/)
- [Entities should always be valid](https://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/#/50)

Comment: thanks; this is the better answer as it gives me better guidance. Mikhail's of course also works in php7.1 but is indeed a bit hacky

Comment: Obviously better than allowing `null` in the entity getter, _however_ the getters in the DTOs should also define return types ideally!

Comment: Additional Link which could be added: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfonycon2018/symfony-forms-rich-domain-models

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP 7.0, which has no nullable return type declaration support, the first option will be the right (non-hacky) choice. In case of you're using PHP 7.1+, you can define a [nullable return type declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php).

```
<?php

class User 
{
    public function getUsername(): ?string {}
}
```