# Symfony form, setters and anemic objects

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm reading the Domain Driver Design book and there is a recommendation to do the methods followed by domain behaviors and not just getters and setters (anemic objects).

But to map an entity on Symfony forms, if I don't put the setter, the form cannot fill the field.

It shows me the error:

`Could not determine access type for property "myField" in class "MyNamespace\MyClass".`

How do you guys deal with that? There is a way do map the field without the setters or the data transformer?

As I know Doctrine does not use the setters to fill the object.

Thank you guys!

Comment: Doctrine uses reflection to directly access private/protected properties.  The Symfony form component uses a [PropertyAccess](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access.html) object to access properties.  You could write (and plugin) your own PropertyAccess object which would have direct access to private/protected properties.  You could also just make your properties public and be done with it.  But the real issue is that Doctrine entities are not the same as Domain entities.  Just not going to work well.

Comment: I agree with @Cerad "_Doctrine entities are not the same as Domain entities_". A real DDD approach is much more complex than this but generally speaking about Symfony forms and Doctrine Entities, a better global approach (in my opinion) is to decouple the Form data binding from your Entities using a DTO (Data Transfert Object), that is a simple POPO (Plain Old PHP Object) to contain your form data. [Take a look at the links referenced in this answer should help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43959421/symfony-form-issue-using-return-type-hinting-in-entity-methods/43962930#43962930)

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys, could you please explain why is not recommended use doctrine entities as domain entities? In this case I could just keep the setters in the doctrine entity and have some layer to transform in the real domain entity, right? But what is the benefit or what problems I will avoid? Thanks!

Comment: @viniciuswebdev if you are asking about how to use some DDD principles (a very very complex argument) in a Symfony/Doctrine project, you will find many answers reading the previously linked book (in my opinion more simpler to understand, for a novice, then the ones written by Eric Evans and others, that you should read after this). Anyway an useful tip to follow is: keep things simple if they works good and, at the same time, you could grow your knowlwdge learning other ways to handle complexity (and the headaches :-)).

Comment: hey @gp_sflover thanks for the answer! Actually, after your comments I'm trying to find an argument to not use the doctrine entities as domain entities. In this approach I can have objects automatically filled by the doctrine and symfony forms and also I can add business behaviors to them. Seems to be a simple approach also.

Answer (score 0):

As ostrolucky pointed out [here](https://gist.github.com/boekkooi/5600b3d43f694f26855d#gistcomment-2281215) you can pass the `property_path` option, read more [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#property-path).

Comment: The link you posted solves a different problem.  Still needs a setter.

Comment: @Cerad the only other thing that crosses my mind is using DTOs in forms and mapping it later to your Entity, what do you think about that?

Comment: DTOs are certainly a valid approach.  It all depends on if you actually have enough business logic inside of your domain entities to make it worth the extra cost.  For the stuff I do, anemic entities work just fine.