# Can I not define the argument type in the setters of an entity due to form validation?

Tags: symfony

When passing an empty value to a `label` field in a form, I get a PHP error caused by Symfony trying to pass null into the setter.

Can I not define the argument type in the setters of an entity due to form validation?

```
class MyEntity {

    ...

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128, nullable=false)
     */
    private $label;

    ....

    public function setLabel(string $label): void
    {
        $this->label = $label;
    }

    ...
```

Comment: Some tips/references to use [DTO's avoiding Entities in Symfony's forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43959421/symfony-form-issue-using-return-type-hinting-in-entity-methods/43962930#43962930)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your entity to be at a valid state you shouldn't link them with your form, you will have to use a DTO object representing your form then update your entity with the values when your form is valid.

The easiest way is to change your setter / getter to be able to return/set null values

```
public function setLabel(string $label = null): void
{
    $this->label = $label;
}
public function getLabel(): ?string
{
    return $this->label;
}
```