# Symfony forms php7 type hints

Tags: php, symfony, php-7

i try to use symfony forms im my symfony 4 project and am running into the following problem:

If i use PHP 7 typehints on my entity e.g.

```
class User {
  private $name;

  public function getName() : string {
    return $this->name;
  }
}
```

and try to let it autofill with the symfony forms bundle:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function postUserAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
    }
```

I get the following error from symfony:

```
Type error: Return value of App\Entity\User::getName() must be of the type string, null returned
```

If i remove the typehint from the entitiy like so:

```
class User {
  private $name;

  public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
  }
}
```

The error is no longer present. I understand that the form is calling the `getName()` function and since the entity is not filled with data yet the return value of the object is `null`.

Is there any way to keep the PHP7 typehints and still use the forms bundle?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33608821/nullable-return-types-in-php7/33609210

Comment: This is only available in php 7.1 not in 7.0

Comment: Of course.  And S4 requires at least 7.1.3.  But do yourself a favor and move directly to 7.2.  There are a couple of odd things with 7.1 that may or may not have been resolved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony: Form issue using Return type hinting in Entity methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43959421/symfony-form-issue-using-return-type-hinting-in-entity-methods)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With php 7.1 you can specify it in this way:

```
public function getName() : ?string {
```

In this way you specify that return values is string or null but only from php 7.1