# Symfony 4.1.4 - Validation annotation NotBlank is not working when edit object data but it works when adding new object

Tags: validation, assert, symfony4

I'm using symfony 4.1.4, I have a wondrous problem, the annotation validation Length is working but NotBlank doesn't work **when edit object** data but it works **when adding new object**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="purchaser", type="string", length=180)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Purchaser is blank")
 * @Assert\Length(min="10", minMessage=" Purchaser min length ....")
 */
private $purchaser;
```

This appears when the lenght less 10 and i'ts fine.
[image]

But when is blank I get this error !!

> Expected argument of type "string", "NULL" given.
>   [image]

** ------------------ EDIT-----------------------**

When I remove **String** from the setter then it works !!

```
    public function setPurchaser(string $purchaser): self
{
    $this->purchaser = $purchaser;

    return $this;
}
```

Or if I keep String and adding **= null** then it works good.

```
 public function setPurchaser(string $purchaser = null): self
```

Comment: Looks like you found one answer. Depending on your php version, it may also help to type-hint with `setPurchaser(?string $purchaser)`. A better approach is discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43962930/546262).

Answer (score 2):

i have the same problem...

When i create a new user with firstName empty, i have the Assert working.
But when i go EDIT him, if i delete my firstName input, this will return the same error of you.

Someone have soluce?

I changed my setter too

```
public function setFirstName(string $firstName): self
{
    $this->firstName = mb_convert_case($firstName, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");

    return $this;
}
```

To

```
public function setFirstName(string $firstName = null): self
{
    $this->firstName = mb_convert_case($firstName, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");

    return $this;
}
```

and this work fine, ty ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use "?string" instead for your setter.